# Any way to automatically pull from a branch daily?

Tags: git, git-pull

We have 2 teams working in an application: The Developers and the infrastructure team.

Developers own the branch "`develop`" coming from `master`
infrastructure owns "`develop-infrastructure`" coming from `develop`

I have the need to pull from branch "`develop`" to "`develop-infrastructure`" every day in order to have the latest changes from the developers.

**Is there a way to automate this process? Does git have something in place for this? Maybe a plugin or other tool?**

Comment: This sounds like a dysfunctional git setup.

Comment: @Flimzy, I am open to suggestions

Comment: You can look into creating a script to pull and using a cron job to execute it everyday. Note that the branch you are pulling into cannot have any changes to it other wise you'll get merge conflicts at all times

Comment: It's hard to offer suggestions without knowing your use-case. I can just say that the way you're using git sounds completely wrong.

Comment: @Flimzy I thanks for your opinion, not very helpful though.

Comment: @miqdadamirali I thought about that, just wondering if there was something already in place to do something like this.

Comment: I never claimed to be able to offer helpful advice without any background info.

Comment: @Flimzy I gave you the background, I explained you what I need, all I am asking is if there is anything anybody else know to automate this. Instead of helping you just voiced your opinion (which didn't help or answer my question), and edit the post so you get some extra points. If you don't have any suggestions, or you are not going to be of any help, why to even bother responding?

Comment: My suggestion is to re-consider how you're using git. Your branching structure is broken. I would be happy to offer a suggestion for something better, but your question does not provide enough context to begin to guess at a better option.

Comment: A starting point would be: Who do your two teams (devs and infra) need two branches in the first place?

Comment: Is there really any reason why they need to be in the same repository?  It's very common practice to have a separate "CICD or Deploy" repository which does not actually contain the application's codebase.

Comment: There is no git command to do this, since as @Flimzy pointed out,  `git` favors a distributed setup, where there is seldom need to "have the latest updates" from someone else constantly. Anything that automates jobs can do this (teamcity, cron, Jenkins etc...), but what you're being hinted is this is an xy question - you didn't state why you want to pull daily - just what is the result. We all know that pulling daily keeps things up-to-date with some other branch - what people are wondering is why? Try and expand on the mode of work of the two teams. Otherwise, you can just use cron.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do this.

Automating `git pull` is impossible. `git pull` is effectivly `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. `git merge` may create merge conflicts, syntactic or semantic, which need human intervention.

The sane way to go about it is to avoid having changes in the branch for too long before merging them back to a common branch (say, `master` or what have you), and make sure that the person who is about to add new changes updates the branch (by `merge` or `rebase` depending on your preferred workflow) before doing so.

Comment: If one team only ever needs visibility of the other team's work then actually it might be provably impossible to have a merge conflict